# OnApplyTemplate() executed before binding correct values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

#### original question with View excerpt

I'm using an adapted version of this [custom control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38361/Circular-gauge-custom-control-for-Silverlight-an) in a MVVM pattern project with the
caliburn micro framework.

```
<gauge:STGaugeControl x:Name="Gauge"
    Radius="120"
    ScaleRadius="105" 
    ScaleStartAngle="120" 
    ResetPointer1OnStartUp="True"
    ScaleSweepAngle="300"
    Pointer1Length="95" 
    Pointer2Length="95" 
    Pointer3Length="95" 
    PointerCapRadius="25" 
    MinValue="{Binding MinGauge, FallbackValue=-6000}" 
    MaxValue="{Binding MaxGauge, FallbackValue=6000}" 
    MajorDivisionsCount="{Binding DivCount, FallbackValue=12}" 
    MinorDivisionsCount="5" 
    CurrentValue1="{Binding Value1}"
    CurrentValue2="{Binding Value2}"
    CurrentValue3="{Binding Value3}"
    ScaleLabelRadius="80"
    ...
    >
```

This is part of my View. Now when the code is running the values are bound and working as expected. But the scale is drawn in a method that is called in OnApplyTemplate() of the custom control and for some reason doesn't have access to the bound values. It uses either the FallbackValue or a default zero value when I remove the fallback.
When I call the scale drawing method while running with a mouse over event for example, it works as intended. 
Is the OnApplyTemplate() called to early to access the binding values or is there something else I'm doing wrong and missed in all the tutorials?

#### custom control code and markup excerpts

Custom control code

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "LayoutRoot", Type = typeof(Grid))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "Pointer1", Type = typeof(Path))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "Pointer2", Type = typeof(Path))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "Pointer3", Type = typeof(Path))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "RangeIndicatorLight", Type = typeof(Ellipse))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PointerCap", Type = typeof(Ellipse))]
public class STGaugeControl : Control
{
#region Private variables
private Grid rootGrid;
*snip*

#region Dependency properties
public static readonly DependencyProperty MinValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MinValue", typeof(double), typeof(STGaugeControl), null);

public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MaxValue", typeof(double), typeof(STGaugeControl), null);

public static readonly DependencyProperty MajorDivisionsCountProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MajorDivisionsCount", typeof(double), typeof(STGaugeControl), null);

public static readonly DependencyProperty MinorDivisionsCountProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MinorDivisionsCount", typeof(double), typeof(STGaugeControl), null);
*snip*

#region Wrapper properties
public double MinValue
{
    get
    {
        return (double)GetValue(MinValueProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MinValueProperty, value);
    }
}

public double MaxValue
{
    get
    {
        return (double)GetValue(MaxValueProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MaxValueProperty, value);
    }
}
*snip*

#region Constructor
static STGaugeControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(STGaugeControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(STGaugeControl)));
}

#region Methods
private static void OnCurrentValue1PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Get access to the instance of CircularGaugeConrol whose property value changed
    STGaugeControl gauge = d as STGaugeControl;
    gauge.OnCurrentValue1Changed(e);
}
*snip*

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    //Get reference to known elements on the control template
    rootGrid = GetTemplateChild("LayoutRoot") as Grid;
    pointer1 = GetTemplateChild("Pointer1") as Path;
    pointer2 = GetTemplateChild("Pointer2") as Path;
    pointer3 = GetTemplateChild("Pointer3") as Path;
    pointerCap = GetTemplateChild("PointerCap") as Ellipse;
    lightIndicator = GetTemplateChild("RangeIndicatorLight") as Ellipse;

    //Draw scale and range indicator
    DrawScale();

    //Set Zindex of pointer and pointer cap to a really high number so that it stays on top of the 
    //scale and the range indicator
    Canvas.SetZIndex(pointer1, 100001);
    Canvas.SetZIndex(pointer2, 100002);
    Canvas.SetZIndex(pointer3, 100003);
    Canvas.SetZIndex(pointerCap, 100005);

    if (ResetPointer1OnStartUp)
    {
        //Reset Pointer
        MovePointer1(ScaleStartAngle);
    }

    if (ResetPointer2OnStartUp)
    {
        //Reset Pointer
        MovePointer2(ScaleStartAngle);
    }

    if (ResetPointer3OnStartUp)
    {
        //Reset Pointer
        MovePointer3(ScaleStartAngle);
    }
}
*snip*

//Drawing the scale with the Scale Radius
public void DrawScale()
{
    //Calculate one major tick angle 
    Double majorTickUnitAngle = ScaleSweepAngle / MajorDivisionsCount;

    //Obtaining One minor tick angle 
    Double minorTickUnitAngle = ScaleSweepAngle / MinorDivisionsCount;

    //Obtaining One major ticks value
    Double majorTicksUnitValue = (MaxValue - MinValue) / MajorDivisionsCount;
    majorTicksUnitValue = Math.Round(majorTicksUnitValue, ScaleValuePrecision);

    Double minvalue = MinValue; ;

    // Drawing Major scale ticks
    for (Double i = ScaleStartAngle; i <= (ScaleStartAngle + ScaleSweepAngle); i = i + majorTickUnitAngle)
    {

        //Majortick is drawn as a rectangle 
        Rectangle majortickrect = new Rectangle();
        majortickrect.Height = MajorTickSize.Height;
        majortickrect.Width = MajorTickSize.Width;
        majortickrect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(MajorTickColor);
        Point p = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        majortickrect.RenderTransformOrigin = p;
        majortickrect.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        majortickrect.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

        TransformGroup majortickgp = new TransformGroup();
        RotateTransform majortickrt = new RotateTransform();

        //Obtaining the angle in radians for calulating the points
        Double i_radian = (i * Math.PI) / 180;
        majortickrt.Angle = i;
        majortickgp.Children.Add(majortickrt);
        TranslateTransform majorticktt = new TranslateTransform();

        //Finding the point on the Scale where the major ticks are drawn
        //here drawing the points with center as (0,0)
        majorticktt.X = (int)((ScaleRadius) * Math.Cos(i_radian));
        majorticktt.Y = (int)((ScaleRadius) * Math.Sin(i_radian));

        //Points for the textblock which hold the scale value
        TranslateTransform majorscalevaluett = new TranslateTransform();
        //here drawing the points with center as (0,0)
        majorscalevaluett.X = (int)((ScaleLabelRadius) * Math.Cos(i_radian));
        majorscalevaluett.Y = (int)((ScaleLabelRadius) * Math.Sin(i_radian));

        //Defining the properties of the scale value textbox
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();

        tb.Height = ScaleLabelSize.Height;
        tb.Width = ScaleLabelSize.Width;
        tb.FontSize = ScaleLabelFontSize;
        tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(ScaleLabelForeground);
        tb.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        //Writing and appending the scale value

        //checking minvalue < maxvalue w.r.t scale precion value
        if (Math.Round(minvalue, ScaleValuePrecision) <= Math.Round(MaxValue, ScaleValuePrecision))
        {
            minvalue = Math.Round(minvalue, ScaleValuePrecision);
            tb.Text = minvalue.ToString();
            minvalue = minvalue + majorTicksUnitValue;

        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        majortickgp.Children.Add(majorticktt);
        majortickrect.RenderTransform = majortickgp;
        tb.RenderTransform = majorscalevaluett;
        rootGrid.Children.Add(majortickrect);
        rootGrid.Children.Add(tb);


        //Drawing the minor axis ticks
        Double onedegree = ((i + majorTickUnitAngle) - i) / (MinorDivisionsCount);

        if ((i < (ScaleStartAngle + ScaleSweepAngle)) && (Math.Round(minvalue, ScaleValuePrecision) <= Math.Round(MaxValue, ScaleValuePrecision)))
        {
            //Drawing the minor scale
            for (Double mi = i + onedegree; mi < (i + majorTickUnitAngle); mi = mi + onedegree)
            {
                //here the minortick is drawn as a rectangle 
                Rectangle mr = new Rectangle();
                mr.Height = MinorTickSize.Height;
                mr.Width = MinorTickSize.Width;
                mr.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(MinorTickColor);
                mr.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                mr.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                Point p1 = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                mr.RenderTransformOrigin = p1;

                TransformGroup minortickgp = new TransformGroup();
                RotateTransform minortickrt = new RotateTransform();
                minortickrt.Angle = mi;
                minortickgp.Children.Add(minortickrt);
                TranslateTransform minorticktt = new TranslateTransform();

                //Obtaining the angle in radians for calulating the points
                Double mi_radian = (mi * Math.PI) / 180;
                //Finding the point on the Scale where the minor ticks are drawn
                minorticktt.X = (int)((ScaleRadius) * Math.Cos(mi_radian));
                minorticktt.Y = (int)((ScaleRadius) * Math.Sin(mi_radian));

                minortickgp.Children.Add(minorticktt);
                mr.RenderTransform = minortickgp;
                rootGrid.Children.Add(mr);


            }

        }

    }
}


}
}
```

Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SpeedTorque">
*snip*

<Style TargetType="local:STGaugeControl" >
    <Setter Property="ResetPointer1OnStartUp" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ResetPointer2OnStartUp" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ResetPointer3OnStartUp" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScaleValuePrecision" Value="5" />
    *snip*
    <Setter Property="GaugeBackgroundColor" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="DialTextColor" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="DialTextFontSize" Value="8" />

    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:STGaugeControl">
                <!-- Root Grid-->
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
                      Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Radius, Converter={StaticResource radiusToDiameterConverter}}" 
                      Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Radius, Converter={StaticResource radiusToDiameterConverter}}" >


                    <Ellipse x:Name="OuterFrame" StrokeThickness="8" 
                             Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Radius, Converter={StaticResource radiusToDiameterConverter}}" 
                             Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Radius, Converter={StaticResource radiusToDiameterConverter}}" 
                             Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=GaugeBackgroundColor, Converter={StaticResource backgroundColorConverter}}">

                        <Ellipse.Stroke>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF636060" Offset="1"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF5F5C5C" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFEEDEDE" Offset="0.35"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFA09595" Offset="0.705"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Stroke>
                    </Ellipse>
                    *snip*
                    
                    <!-- Pointer1 -->
                    <Path x:Name="Pointer1" Stroke="#FFE91C1C" StrokeThickness="2" 
                          Width="{TemplateBinding Pointer1Length}" 
                          Height="{TemplateBinding Pointer1Thickness}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          Data="M1,1 L1,10 L156,6 z" Stretch="Fill"  RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.5" 
                          RenderTransform="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                        Path=Pointer1Length, Converter={StaticResource pointerCenterConverter}}"
                          Visibility="{TemplateBinding Pointer2Visibility}" >
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#33890A0A" Offset="0.197"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#33C40808" Offset="1"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#33E32323" Offset="0.61"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Path.Fill>
                    </Path>
                    *snip*

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Scaling and layout should be done in Measure and Arrange, not in OnApplyTemplate. The only real uses I've found for if is getting references to named parts of your control.

Comment: What do you mean with *"the scale is drawn in a method that is called in OnApplyTemplate()"*? *OnApplyTemplate* is invoked when a ControlTemplate is set for this control -- do you try expressing that the scale is part of a ControlTemplate that is being assigned to this control?

Comment: @Zache: could you elaborate on that "Measure and Arrange", first time I hear of it.

Comment: @elgonzo: yes, the scale is part of the control template. It is unchanged from the custom gauge template I linked in the question, if you don't what to check in there I can add part of the code for understanding.

Comment: @Stefan, then please add the the control template to your question. It is not practical to require others to visit that project's website, download the source code package and look out for the XAML file that contains the control template... If the control template is longer than 20...30 lines, do not post it completely in your question but cut out any part of it that is not related to the scale...

Comment: WPF has a system for layout, simplified it works in two stages: Measure and Arrange. In the measure stage parent controls tell their child controls what space is available and the child returns their desired size. Once we know how big everything wants to be the final size is calculated and sent down the chain from parent to child.

OnApplyTemplate is called when ApplyTemplate is called, that happens on every Measure.

Comment: @Stefan, in the XAML of the template i do not see anything related to a scale. Well, curiosity got the better of me, and i did a peek into the source code. Well, you were close to the truth by saying that the scale is drawn in the OnApplyTemplate() (okay, it's not drawn; rather the UI elements for the scale are instantiated there, but that is just a minor thing). Frankly, this control suffers from its implementation, and i would strongly discourage you from using it. (contd...)

Comment: However, if you still want to stick with it although it is not a well-behaved control (who cares whether it works as long as it looks fancy :-D), you might try a workaround if you dare to: in the source code for the Gauge control, implement property-changed-callback(s) for any DependencyProperty which is related to the scale and for which you establish bindings. In the property-change-callback, trigger the draw methods for the scale (in a similar manner as OnApplyTemplate() does. You would still need to implement some to remove the UIelements of the old/incorrect scale, though. (contd...)

Comment: Another option for the property-changed-callback could be trying to apply another dummy controltemplate to the gauge and then re-apply the original template again (which triggers OnApplyTemplate() again). Note, that your dummy template must contain the same named elements which are extracted in the OnApplyTemplate() method. The quickest way to ensure this is to make a duplicate of the original control template with a different resource key and using it as the dummy template. In any case, if you want to stick with the control, it is probably the best to ask the author to improve the control.

Comment: @elgonzo Thank you very much, especially for taking the time to check the original template. I'll probably have to use one of the workarounds, since I don't have the time right now to implement that functionality on my own.  Do you have any tutorials/examples on hand on how I would go about drawing that scale in an appropriate way for when I have time?

Comment: For drawing/creating the scale itself (in terms of how calculate the coordinates and other attributes of the UIElements which make up the scale), just look at the code of the Gauge control. Trying to fix this control would require getting a better understanding of how its parts work and play together and then rework the code. This is most likely not quickly done with little effort. I don't know whether there are some tutorials about how to create a true and proper WPF Gauge/Scale control (i am sorry). Perhaps there are. I would say rather google around for a better Gauge control instead... :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you need to bind your scale to a VM property and recalculate it each time you change the parameters it depends on. 
I imagine you will need to update your Scale property in the VM each time a new value is set to MinGauge or MaxGauge.

Comment: The scale is only drawn once, but it depends on the signal that is assigned to the template on creation. In the original template the values are fixed, but I was advised to adhere to a code scheme where the signal and the min and max values are assigned on creation through parameters. Also the gauge element is used multiple times inside a parent view, each with different signals and min/max values. The values are bound to the same VM as the values for the pointers (CurrentValue1/2/3) which are changing while the program is running. When running all values are accesible like I expect.